# Clarks and RideRever Caliper Pad Spacing

Tags: caliper

We've had a horrible time adjusting RideRever and Clarks hydraulic disk brakes in the shop.

I visually observed that the pistons pull back only very little when the lever is released.

I compared both calipers along with a Shimano MT200.

For each, I pushed back the pistons, inserted a new disc (1.8mm), depressed the lever multiple times, removed the disc and measure with a digital caliper the space between the pads at 3 different places. Pads are new on all calipers.

For the Clarks and the Riderever, I measured 1.8-1.90. On the Shimano, I measured 2.8.

Apart from push ratios for hypothetical higher leverage in the system, the difference is stricking.

Not surprising, it's impossible to adjust the Clarks and the RideRever to have no rubbing, or acceptable rubbing.

I will try to wear the RideRever out, and before that, lube the pistons with mineral oil. Those have been factory bleed and not shortened.

Questions:

- Could they still need a bleed? Theoretically, air in the system could cause this.
- Aside from piston lubing, burning them in and bleeding, what would other options be?
- Is their not solutions because of the low quality product?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I went ahead and lube the pistons and bled one of the RideRever brake. The feeling was far better afterward. Visually, the pistons' travel is longer. I have confirmed this with the digital caliper: I get 1.9mm consistently.

That brake is not fitted on a bike, so the reality check will come later.

There is a bike with 2 of those that will need to be bled and I'll share the results here.

Comment: Clarks rotors are 1.80-1.88mm, so basically the brakes won't even clear their own rotors (I was curious if they were expecting extra thin rotors). Have you full spread the calipers after lubing them?